# My React code get crash some time but not always

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, state

I am building a project in which there is only a single question and it changes when pressing the refresh button. Everything is going well but sometimes the code crashes and the page gets blank (as shown in attached image) on pressing the refresh button.

```js
import React from "react"
import questionsData from '../questionsData.js'

function Content(){

    const [question, setQuestion] = React.useState({
        heading:"",
        hints : []
    })

    const [refresh, setRefresh] = React.useState(0)
    

    React.useEffect(function(){
        if(questionsData){
            const randomNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * questionsData.length) + 1
         
            let headinggg = questionsData[randomNo].heading
            let hintsss = questionsData[randomNo].hints
            setQuestion({
              heading: headinggg,
              hints: hintsss
            })
        }else{
           document.write("loading")
        }
        
         
    },[refresh])

  const sugg = question.hints.map((hint) => {
      return(
          <li>{hint}</li>
      )
  })

  function renderQuestion(){
        setRefresh(refresh + 1)
  }

    return(
            <div className="content">
                <div className="question">
                        <h4>{question.heading}</h4>
                        <br />
                        <span>You should say:</span> 
                        <ul>
                           {sugg} 
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <div className="action">
                    <div className="record">
                        <img src="images/211859_mic_icon.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="refresh" onClick={renderQuestion}>
                        <img src="images/3994399_refresh_reload_repeat_rotate_sync_icon.svg" alt="" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    ) 
}

export default Content
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Open the console and check the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `+ 1` from the `randomNo` calculation, otherwise it could case an IndexOutOfBounds error:

```
const randomNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * questionsData.length);
```